# How can I search only in my favorite tags?

Tags: support, tags, questions, search, tag-watching

I have several favorite tags and I want to view relevant questions. How can I search only in my favorite tags?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have [*marked*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19177/294055) your favorite tags as such, then you can use the following two operators, as explained in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching):

> - `intags:mine` returns only posts that appear in tags you have marked as favorite. (If you don't have any tags, this operator does nothing. For better results, update your preferences.)
> - `is:question` narrows results down to just questions [...]

So, if you put both operators into the search box, then you should find all questions that appear in tags you have marked as favorite.

Comment: Clickable:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 1):

Use it by adding `+or+` in between tags in URL. Something like.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+or+oracle+or+unix+or+linux
```

By default it will be sorted with `newest` on top.

This is applicable for other StackExchange sites as well.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually finally implemented with [Custom Filters](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/25/introducing-custom-filters/)

[image]